# How to reload different jsf menuItem page fragment inside the <ui:include src"#"> tag

Tags: jsf-2, oracle-adf, ajax4jsf

I want to display different menu page fragment in the  tag when the particular commandMenuItem is clicked the default page fragment is being displayed properly but the page is not refreshing upon the menu click getting the page id through the actionListner but still its not refreshing My Code for the same is :-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<af:document title="untitled2.jsf" id="d1">
<af:form id="f1">
<a4j:form ajaxSubmit="true" reRender="content">
<panelGrid>
<af:menuBar id="mb1">
<af:menu text="menu 1" id="m1">
<af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 1" id="menuPage" actionListener="#{PageBean.getMenu}" action="menuPage.jsff">
<a4j:ajax execute="@form" render=":content"/>
</af:commandMenuItem>
</af:menu>
<af:menu text="menu 2" id="m2">
<af:commandMenuItem text="commandMenuItem 2" id="menuPage2" actionListener="#{PageBean.getMenu}" action="menuPage1.jsff">
<a4j:ajax execute="@form" render=":content"/>
</af:commandMenuItem>
</af:menu>
</af:menuBar>
<ui:insert name="content">
<ui:include src="#{PageBean.page}.jsff"/>
</ui:insert>
</panelGrid>
</a4j:form>
</af:form>
</af:document>
</f:view>
```

My actionListner Bean that is being used to track and update the the dynamic page value in the page variable being used to display the page in the  is :-

**PageBean(bean for the action listner)**

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
public class PageBean {
String page = "menuPage";
    public PageBean() {
}
    public void getMenu(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
    String id = actionEvent.getComponent().getId();
    System.out.println(" Menu ID : "+id);
    page = id;
}

    public String getPage() {
    return page;
}
```

}

Now i want that when i click on the commanMenuItem2 from the menu2 then the related page menuPage2 containing outputText value menu page 2 will appear instead of menu page 1

Comment: What is the scope of your managed bean? It should be `@ViewScoped`. If it is I think it should work.

Comment: Please try to do it also with `@RequestScoped`. Have you debugged this? Is `PageBean.setPage()`/`PageBean.getPage()` called? I don't see `setPage()` method in your bean. Maybe this is it?

Comment: You can also try to change `actionListener` with `action`. You need to debug this, check if listener is fired up and page is setted correctly.

Comment: @pepuch..actionListner is working fine and also the value in the page variable is set as i am checking the same in the actionListner by displaying the page value in system.out.println and it is giving me the correct id value of the menu pressed and I set the id of the menu same as the page fragment name that i want to open upon the menu click, the problem is with the reRendering of the <ui:include src="#> as it is not being Rerendred and refreshed upon menu click there is some problem with this component related to render response more than once...